# Xquery, counting value occurrence in descendants

Tags: xml, xquery

Let’s say we have the file resturants.xml which looks like

```
<restaurant>
   <name>Benny’s hamburgers</name>
   <chef>Benny</chef>
</restaurant>
<restaurant>
   <name>The Restaurant</name>
   <chef>Oliver</chef>
</restaurant>
<restaurant>
   <name>Italian’s</name>
   <chef>Oliver</chef>
</restaurant>
<restaurant>
   <name>La pasta</name>
   <chef>Oliver</chef>
</restaurant>
```

and we want to return the name of the chefs that works on 2 or more restaurants and the name of those resturants, how would that XQuery code look like?

I have tried using

```
$xml = doc("resturants.xml")
for $restaurant in $xml/restaurant
   where count($restaurant/chef) >= 2
   return $restaurant/name
```

but that seems to return the name of the resturant with at least 2 chefs with the same name. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XQuery won't automatically join data for you. Also, it helps to think about this type of problem from the other direction. Since you want to associate a chef with multiple restaurants, you can get unique chef names first, and then join with associated restaurants.

```
for $name in distinct-values($xml/restaurant/chef)
let $restaurants := $xml/restaurant[chef = $name]
where count($restaurants) >= 2
return 
  element chef {
    element name { $name },
    element restaurants {
      $restaurants/name
    }
  }
```

Comment: My goodness, thank you! Kudos for the element-tag, didn't know it but it will sure come in handy :)